# Tuple Array with names - is it possible?

Tags: c#, typescript

How can I achieve something like that (C#) in Typescript

`var items = new List<(string Pointer, string Value)>();` (c#)

`if (items.Any(x => x.Pointer == "asdf"))`  (c#)?

I have `Array<[string, string]>` (ts)

but I cannot assign names to it

e.g `[Pointer: string, Value: string]` (ts)

and lambda lets me use index, but can I use name?

`items.some(e => e[0] ==` (ts)

Comment: I don't think you can have named tuples in TS. It's either an array, so you have indexed items, or it's an object and you have properties. Not sure you can do both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in typescript you need to do this

```
items : Array<{pointer:string, value:string}>;
```

and if you want to instantiate

```
items = [{pointer:"a", value:"1"},{pointer:"b", value:"2"}];
```

to check if `Any`

```
items.some(x => x.pointer === "asdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by declaring the tuple then specifying the types for each of the tuple values:

```
let stringPromise = AsyncStringFunction();
let numberPomise = AsyncNumberFunction();
let customerPomise = AsyncCustomerFunction();

let [stringResult, numberResult, customerResult]: [string, number, CustomerModel] =
    await Promise.all([stringPromise, numberPromise, customerPromise]);
```